# Tex equation block highlighting in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting, tex

I would like to highlight `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` Tex environments with a different color in org-mode.

Inline Tex expressions (delimited by the `$` symbol) can be highlighted as follows:

```
(defface dollar-face
  '((t (:foreground "orange")))
  "Face for dollar sign")
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode '(("\\<$.*?$\\>" . 'dollar-face)))
```

However, the same idea does not seem to work when the region to highlight spans several lines.

As an alternative, I could use source blocks, which are correctly highlighted:

```
#+NAME: eq:test
#+BEGIN_equation
\lambda_{3}vH^{3}
#+END_equation
```

However, all sorts of additional symbols are added once I export the document to tex (via `org-latex-export-to-pdf`), and the tex compiler complains. As an example, the above is converted to

```tex
\begin{equation}
\(\lambda\)\textsubscript{3}vH\textsuperscript{3}
\label{org9ad646c}
\end{equation}
```

How should I proceed to highlight any tex equation block in org-mode, without affecting their export behavior to the tex format?